# Similar algorithm as Bayes prediction

Tags: algorithm, math, probability, bayesian, prediction

I'm using Bayes algorithm to predict new incoming data.  Its running on test data, so I can look how good prediction is. Each new data item has number of properties with information about learning data, so its like:

```
feature1: 0.15
feature2: 0.26
feature3: 0.8
...
```

My pseudo-code in details:

```
for item in new_data:
    rank = 0
    for feature in item:
         rank += log(feature_probability(feature))
    rank = rank/number_of_features
    rank_data.append(rank)
filter(rank_data)
```

By `filter(rank_data)` I mean cutting lowest part in sorted `rank_data`. 
Every item in data has it's *quality number* which we can't operate (because in real life we don't know it), only to check the quality of prediction, so the point is to cut lowest sum of that *quality numbers*. By the way - features probabilities is a mean of quality numbers from some learning data.

That Bayes prediction here (same as geometrical mean in our terms) is doing fine, but I'm looking for some better results algorithm.

I've read some sort of math works to find it myself but it's too hard to implement it in my kind of data.

Comment: [Mahalanobis_distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) paired with [Likelyhood Ratio Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test) if you can assume that the features describe a multivariate gaussian distribution.  This can be found in prob and stats for electrical engineers if you want to find a good reference for its application.

Comment: I've found some book with that name and it's pretty good by the way but nothing about Mahalanobis distance:( Not really sure how to implement it - if use it as a metric for each vector it's going to increase number of operations to N*N what I wouldn't be able to handle or I'm not understand it well by now. @Felix Castor

Comment: No doubt it will increase the operations.  [Math.Numerics](http://mathnetnumerics.codeplex.com/) has many of the algorithms needed to help.  The Mahalanobis distance becomes it's own random variable given test features and their distance from each classification.  The likelihood that a list of features belongs with a particular classification still needs to be calculated after that considering overlap may occur or the cost of miscalculating one feature is much greater than another.  Mahalanobis alone may be sufficient for you application.  The inverse covariance matrix is the most costly op.